# Free API for handwritten OCR (Optical Character Recognition)

Tags: gratis, api, ocr, text-processing

I wanted to know if there are any free APIs available for text recognition from a handwritten document. I looked in Google Vision API, Microsoft Cognitive API but all of the above are paid. So is it possible to use open source APIs to recognize handwritten documents? I looked into Tesseract API but it is not able to recognize handwritten documents.